# Web Scrape Attempt With Selenium Yields Duplicate Entries

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-structures

I am attempting to scrape some data off of [this website](https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/farming).
I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

There are 30 entries per page and I'm currently trying to scrape information from within each of the links on each page. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print(driver.title)
driver.get("https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/farming")
time.sleep(1)
select = driver.find_element_by_id("listings")

page_entries = [i.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
                for i in select.find_elements_by_tag_name("h4")]

columns = {"ESTABLISHMENT YEAR":[], "EMPLOYEES":[], "COMPANY MANAGER":[],
                  "VAT REGISTRATION":[], "REGISTRATION CODE":[]}


for i in page_entries:
    print(i)
    driver.get(i)
          
    listify_subentries = [i.text.strip().replace("\n","") for i in 
                    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info")][:11]
```

***Everything runs fine up to here.The problem is likely in the section below.***

```
    for i in listify_subentries:
        for q in columns.keys():
            if q in i:
                item = i.replace(q,"")
                print(item)
                columns[q].append(item)
            else:
                columns[q].append("None given")
                print("None given")
```

[Here's a picture of the layout for one entry. Sorry I can't yet embed images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcNmX.png)

I'm trying to scrape some of the information under the "Working Hours" box (i.e. establishment year, company manager etc) from every business's page. You can find the exact information under the `columns` variable.

Because the not all pages have the same amount of information under the "Working Hours" box ([here is one with more details underneath it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNO2o.png)), I tried using dictionaries + text manipulation to look up the available sub-entries and obtain the relevant information to their right. That is to say, obtain the name of the company manager, the year of establishment and so on; and if a page did not have this, then it would simply be tagged as "None given" under the relevant sub-entry.

The idea is to collate all this information and export it to a dataframe later on. Inputting "None given" when a page is lacking a particular sub-entry allows me to preserve the integrity of the data structure so that the entries are sure to align.

However, when I run the code the output I receive is completely off.

[Here is the outer view of the columns dictionary once the code has run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCYA.png)

[And if I click on the 'COMPANY MANAGER' section, you can see that there are multiple instances of it saying "None given" before it gives the name of company manager on the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ts6H.png)  This is repeated for every other sub-entry as you'll see if you run the code and scroll down. I'm not sure what went wrong, but it seems that the size of the list has been inflated by a factor of 10, with extra "None given"s littered here and there. The size of each list should be 30, but now its 330.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next example how to iterate all enterprises on that page and save the various info into a dataframe:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/farming"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for a in soup.select("h4 > a"):
    u = "https://www.businesslist.com.ng" + a["href"]
    print(u)
    data = {"URL": u}
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")
    for info in s.select("div.info:has(.label)"):
        label = info.select_one(".label")
        label.extract()
        value = info.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        data[label.get_text(strip=True)] = value
    all_data.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                  URL                        Company name                                                                                                             Address                         Phone Number       Mobile phone                                                                                                                                                                                         Working hours Establishment year                                                                                                                                               Employees              Company manager Share this listing                                                                                                                                  Location map                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Products & Services                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Listed in categories                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Keywords                                  Website Registration code VAT registration        E-mail             Fax
0              https://www.businesslist.com.ng/company/198846/macmed-integrated-farms             Macmed Integrated Farms                              1, Gani Street, Ijegun Imore. Satellite Town. Lagos , Lagos , Lagos , Nigeria View Map                          08033316905        09092245349                                                                              Monday: 8am-5pm Tuesday: 8am-5pm Wednesday: 8am-5pm Thursday: 8am-5pm Friday: 8am-5pm Saturday: 8am-5pm Sunday: 10am-4pm               2013                                                                                                                                                     1-5            Engr. Marcus Awoh                                                 Show Map Expand Map 1, Gani Street, Ijegun Imore. Satellite Town. Lagos , Lagos , Lagos , Nigeria Get Directions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Macmed Integrated Farms is into Poultry, Fish Farming (eggs, meat,day old chicks,fingerlings and grow-out) and animal Husbandry and sales of Farmlands land and facilities We also provide feasibility studies and business planning for all kind of businesses.                                                                                                                         Day old chicks WE are receiving large quantity of Day old Pullets, Broilers and cockerel in December 2016.\nInterested buyers are invited. PRICE: N 100 - N 350 Investors/ Partners We Macmed Integrated Farms a subsidiary of Macmed Cafe Limited RC (621444) are into poultry farming situated at Iponsinyi, behind (Nigerian National Petroleum Marketing Company)NNPMC at Mosimi, along... Commercial Hatchery Macmed Integrated Farms is setting up a Hatchery for chicken and other birds. We have 2 nos of fully automatic incubator imported from China with combined capacity of 1,500 eggs per setting.\nPlease book in advance.\nMarcus Awoh.\nfarm Operations Manager. PRICE: N100 - N250                                                                      Business Services Business Services / Consultants Business Services / Small Business Business Services / Small Business / Business Plans Business Services / Animal Shelters Manufacturing & Industry Manufacturing & Industry / Farming Manufacturing & Industry / Farming / Poultry Housing Suppliers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Catfish Day old chicks Farming FINGERLINGS Fishery grow out and aquaculture Meat Poultry eggs spent Pol MORE +4                                      NaN               NaN              NaN           NaN             NaN

...
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]